# Create a column of a pyspark dataframe using two other pyspark dataframes as key values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe in pyspark

```
Date | Value | Date2
2019/01/10 | 9.5 | null
2019/01/10 | 9.5 | null
2019/01/11 | 4.5 | 2019/01/10
2019/01/12 | 6.7 | 2019/01/11
2019/01/12 | 6.7 | 2019/01/10
2019/01/13 | 9.2 | 2019/01/12
2019/01/14 | 13.6 | 2019/01/13
2019/01/15 | 2.7 | 2019/01/14
2019/01/16 | 7.8 | 2019/01/15
```

and I want to create a new column whose values are those of the column 'Value' but indexed by the column Date 2 (taking as index Date). The desired output would be something like:

```
Date | Value | Date2 | Value2
2019/01/10 | 9.5 | null | null
2019/01/10 | 9.5 | null | null
2019/01/11 | 4.5 | 2019/01/10 | 9.5
2019/01/12 | 6.7 | 2019/01/11 | 4.5
2019/01/12 | 6.7 | 2019/01/10 | 9.5
2019/01/13 | 9.2 | 2019/01/12 | 6.7
2019/01/14 | 13.6 | 2019/01/13 | 9.2
2019/01/15 | 2.7 | 2019/01/14 | 13.6
2019/01/16 | 7.8 | 2019/01/15 | 2.7
```

is there a solution that does not involve a join?

Answer (score 0):

If not a large df, susbset, rename columns and join. Code below

```
df.join(df.select('Date','Value').toDF('Date2', 'Value2'), how='left', on='Date2').show()
```

If the df is big, try creating a python dict of the columns Date and Vlue and then map to Date2. Code below

```
from itertools import chain
d = {row['Date']: row['Value']  for row in df.collect()}#Create dict of the columns

m_expr1 = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*d.items())])#Mapping expression
#map to date2
df.withColumn("val2", m_expr1[F.col("Date2")]).show()
```

Comment: very good but it is a large dataset and cannot be done with a join. It's the first idea that had occurred to me.

Comment: You should have stated so. See my edits above and check if that makes it easier and feasible

Comment: in the statement, at the end I have put if it is possible to do it without the join